# Unexpected query result in mysql select query

Tags: sql, date, mariadb, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to run a MySQL query to get the last production quantity (which was the quantity added previously by user which in this scenario is 7) from a table called production but what I get is the highest production. These are the tables:

```
_____ Production ___________
"production_id","prod_id","production_date","production_qty"
"1","40001","2020-04-15","35"
"2","40002","2019-02-08","54"
"3","40002","2020-04-08","67"
"4","40001","2020-04-02","76"
"5","40001","2020-05-08","21"
"6","40001","2020-04-29","34"
"7","40003","2020-04-03","545"
"8","40003","2020-04-18","7"
"9","40001","2020-04-25","6"
"10","40001","2020-04-25","6"
"11","40001","2020-04-25","6"
"12","40002","2020-04-13","5"
"13","40003","2020-04-01","5"
"14","40001","2020-04-17","3"
"15","40003","2020-04-04","2"
"16","40002","2020-04-11","45"
"17","40001","2020-04-02","4"
"18","40002","2020-04-01","3"
"19","40003","2020-04-17","2"
"20","40003","2020-04-29","3"

______ Products ____________
"product_id","product_name","product_unit","product_group","product_size"
"40001","tested","Gram","EVA","7/10"
"40002","testing","KG","EVA","7/10"
"40003","teste454","KG","PU","7/10"
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT product_id, product_unit, production_qty, SUM(production_qty) as prod_in_hand FROM 
products JOIN production ON products.product_id = production.prod_id WHERE product_id = 
40003 AND production_date < CURRENT_DATE
```

The above query genrates this result:

```
prod_id, product_unit, production_qty, prod_in_hand
40003, KG, 545, 561
```

But I am expecting "7" as production_qty.
How can I do that?
I am using XAMPP Server phpMyAdmin MariaDB server version 10.3.16

Comment: are you using `MySQL 8.0`? and also post your expected output.

Comment: You are summing everything with production date < current_date and you are not using a group by so the non aggregated columns are indeterminate. Is there only ever 1 entry per production date? If so why are you summing?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization. When you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Your query is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy last mean the last entry made of this particular product and if I group by then I get multiple entries but only one is required

Comment: "the last entry made" is not any clearer than "the last". How exactly does one identify it? You need to say this clearly. What does "I get multiple entries" mean? Again, if you just write a few fuzzy words & don't clearly actually clearly say what you mean in terms of code & parts of input & output then you are not clear. And if you don't write clearly then you can't search or communicate. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Please read & follow the site protocols. Getting an answer says nothing about how clear or appropriate your question is. Questions here are expected to be helpful to others in the future, not just get answers for the asker. Plus I am telling you things to help you in the future & to help the site not be cluttered by poor questions. [help]

Comment: @philipxy Gotcha! thanks, I'll keep it in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this as a greatest-n-per-group problem, where you want to retrieve the "last" record from `production` for each record in `products`. Here is on approach using a correlatd subquery for filtering:

```
select
    ps.*,
    pn.production_date,
    pn.production_qty
from products ps
inner join production pn 
    on pn.prod_id = ps.product_id
where pn.production_date = (
    select max(pn1.production_date)
    from production pn1
    where pn1.prod_id = ps.product_id
)
```

If you are running MySQL 8.0 (or MariaDB 10.2), you can also use `row_number()` for this:

```
select *
from (
    select
        ps.*,
        pn.production_date,
        pn.production_qty,
        row_number() over(partition by ps.product_id order by pn.production_date desc) rn
    from products ps
    inner join production pn 
        on pn.prod_id = ps.product_id
) t
where rn = 1
```